# Image sliders in separate divs - Multiple slider effects in one html page or one div?

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I have a problem with the creation of a jquery slider(content scroller, image slider)

I would like to include different areas of the slider with different images and transitions.
For example **the images on the left to scroll down,the middle images to fade and 
the upper part to scroll up**. Maybe it will be on next-to-other divs? I dont know!!!

**Basically to be able animate elements of each slide independently next-to-each other but with
different transition.**

I suppose I will use jquery on this but to you have in mind any **suggestion/code or 
aproach?**

Any help would be highly apreciated guys!!!

Comment: I'd look for one slider plugin with multiple directions & effects. Personally I like bxslider. http://bxslider.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think this would be your best bet its not quite what you are looking for but its well documented and has varying effects at random:

http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/